# Tiny MCE - set full-screen when editor is loaded?

Tags: javascript, iframe, tinymce

I use tiny_mce as word-like editor in textareas that are in iframes. I want to use whole iframe space. TinyMCE has a fullscreen button, but I need to set full-screen mode automatically when plugin has loaded. Is there a function/trigger to call this mode (or the button)? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the IFRAME document you can instruct TinyMCE to switch to fullscreen mode once the textarea has initialized. The following code will need to go into your IFRAME:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "description",  // This is the id of the textarea
    plugins : "fullscreen",
    theme : "advanced",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "fullscreen,code",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    oninit : function() {  // Once initialized, tell the editor to go fullscreen
        tinyMCE.get('description').execCommand('mceFullScreen');
    }
});
</script>

....

<textarea id="description"></textarea>
```

The TinyMCE fullscreen plugin will fill up the current window - and, since the IFRAME is it's own window, the this should fill the IFRAME.

**Edit:** This technique can also be used with the TinyMCE JQuery library. The options are the same but the invocation syntax is a little different. Again, the key lines are the `oninit` callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#description').tinymce({   // "description" is the id of the TEXTAREA
        // ... same options inserted here ...
        oninit : function() {
            tinyMCE.get('description').execCommand('mceFullScreen');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: How to set content in tinymce when its in fullscreen

Answer (score 1):

You just need to insert the following code into the tinyMCE.init({}) function:

```
setup : function(ed) {
  ed.on('load',function(e){
      ed.execCommand('mceFullScreen');
  });
```

},

Ps: remember the comma if you have other instruction after it or it will fail.
;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(\'(function(){tinyMCE.get("YourElementID").execCommand("mceFullScreen");})()\',2500);
```

Comment: Explain what the code does in your answer and edit it!